# How do you make a list in Haskell using two numbers?

Tags: list, haskell, numbers

Here is my problem: Declare type and define a function that takes two numbers m and n as input and returns a list containing the doubled values of all odd integers between m and n. For instance, fun 2 11 would return [6, 10, 14, 18, 22].

I don't know how I can take the two number 2 and 11 and make it into a list [2..11]. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use sequence generation (range syntax):

```
Prelude> [2 .. 11]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Works for symbolic values, too:

```
Prelude> let [m,n] = [2,11]
Prelude> [m .. n]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Comment: +1 moreover `[6, 10, 14, 18, 22]` == `[6, 10 .. 22]`

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work with Haskell for almost two years, so correct me if I'm wrong and it doesn't work:

```
getDoubledOdd :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
getDoubledOdd m n = map (2*) $ filter odd [m..n]
```

Comment: No,first grab the odd numbers, then double: for [2..11], odds are [3,5,7,9,11], double them to get [6,10,14,18,22].  But I don't think OP was asking us to solve the whole problem for him.

Comment: You can write `(\x -> 2 * x)` as just `(2 *)`.

Comment: thanks a lot! Your code was helpful. This is what I did:
getOdd m n = map (*2) (filter odd [(m)..(n)])

Comment: @user2921302 you can do without some of those parentheses. You need the ones around `*2`, but not around `m` or `n`.  Also, whenever you have *something* `(` *whole rest of line* `)` you can use *something* `$` *whole rest of line* instead.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of list comprehension and range would be the most standard way to do it.

`[ 2*x | x <- [2..11], odd x ]`

The code basically says "let x loop from 2 to 11 (x <- [2..11]), and if x is odd (odd x), put 2*x into the list that will be returned".

Hope that explains.

Comment: you can avoid your N `odd` comparisons and reduce list generation in 1/2 factor...

Comment: I saw your comment on the very top. Yours is the simplest for sure. I just think list comprehension is more flexible. Thank you for commenting. @josejuan

Comment: yes, use comprehension lists but think about upper/lower bounds and step to use... :)

Comment: Oh do you mean [ 2*x | x <- [3,5..11]]? @josejuan

Comment: no, no :) `doubleOdds a b = [c, c + 4 .. b + b] where c = shift (a .|. 1) 1` ;)

Comment: Oh I see. Very nice. Thank you :) @josejuan